# Maintaining State with def ref in Clojure

Tags: function, clojure, state, ref

I have the following function:

```
(defn best-move [tracked-moves]
  (def all-scores (ref tracked-moves))
    @all-scores)
```

Its being called by a recursive function.
I want to be able to keep passing in tracked-moves, and for them to all exist within 
@all-scores.
The way it is written right now, @all-scores will only hold onto the last tracked-moves that it is given.  How can I get it to hold onto all of the data that it receives every time the best-move function is called?  And to not just return the last of all the data it receives?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `def` incorrectly. Any use of `def` (and `defn`) will create a namespace-level var. It doesn't matter where you call `def`. As you've pointed out, you're continuously redefining `all-scores`. The short answer is to pull your definition of `all-scores` to the top level, so you're not constantly invoking it. Then, update the `ref` as described in the [documentation](http://clojure.org/refs). If you're not using transactions, and don't need to manage multiple refs, you might want to use [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) instead.

Comment: Thanks! The example in the documentation is a bit heavy; could you provide a newbie friendly example?